Where is the setting to remove the name of the venv from VS Code's terminal prompt?
Whenever I'm accessing a venv from the VS Code terminal, VS Code adds the name of the venv to the beginning of each prompt, which I've highlighted here:

The issue here is that I use Starship, which already handles displaying the venv, so this behavior is redundant and cluttering.
Is there a setting in VSCode that will let me turn this off? I'm on macOS.

This doesn't seem like a VS Code thing, but instead a virtualenv/or-whatever-tool-you're-using thing.

Have you checked if it also gets added when activating the venv outside of VS Code? Because it's the venv that updates your terminal prompt to add the name of the venv. In this case, seems you are using poetry, so you'll have to configure your poetry venv not to display its name.

If you are indeed using poetry, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63410624/2745495

It turns out this is an issue with how the VSCode terminal interacts with Starship: https://github.com/spaceship-prompt/spaceship-prompt/issues/19
Adding export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 to my .zshrc before exporting Starship fixed this for me.
